# Postgres | Ensure at least one row is available

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with following columns:

```
type varchar
value varchar
column_1 <> 
column_2 <>
....
```

I want to ensure whenever I update or delete in the table, following condition should always hold:

*For each type, there should be at least one row with value = `default`*

---

So for example:

```
id | Type | Value
-----------------
1  | T1   | v1
2  | T2   | default
3  | T2   | default
4  | T1   | default
```

In this case, I cannot delete id 4, since then table will not have any row with default value for T1 type.

---

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly implement this in the deletion/update logic itself.  For example, to do a safe delete according to your rules you could try:

```sql
DELETE
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    id = 4 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                       WHERE t2.Type = t1.Type AND
                             t2.id <> 4 AND
                             t2.Value = 'default');
```

You could use a similar exists logic for the updates.

Comment: Can work, except I am designing the DB and it would be used by other developers. Needless to say, some might forget to add this logic. But this gives me at least a starting point to think

Comment: You could also implement this via a trigger, which would not require the developers to do anything extra.  But I sort of prefer handling it from the application logic if possible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: It depends on the situation, is it application logic or data logic? And how many applications do you have that use this data? And what's the impact when some application is implemented without this check?